# Javascript: Update label content while typing inside of a parent input with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to update with jquery the label of preview div when im typing inside of the parent input of edit div?
Thank you.

```
<html>
        <body>
                <div id="preview">
                        <label id="companyName" class="workExperience">
                                This is my company
                        </label>
                </div>
                <div id="edit">
                        <label>Company Name: </label>
                        <input type="text" id="companyName" />
                </div>
        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you rephrase a bit? Among other things, I find "parent input" evry confusing; the `<input />` element isn't parent to anything.

Comment: Note that `keyup` doesn't react to pasting with the mouse and `change` doesn't update "as-you-type".

Comment: Exact duplicate of [your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3461876/javascript-edit-a-preview-with-jquery)

Comment: No, the question was http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462515/javascript-input-to-get-the-current-value-of-the-label-elements
Bue seems like noone understood

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd have to have something along these lines in your code:

```
<script>
$("#companyName").keyup(function () {
  var value = $(this).val();
  $(".workExperience").text(value);
}).keyup();
</script>
```

However, I would **NOT** give them the same id value, as it might lead to some errors.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

you can not have the same ID in the tag  "label" and the tag "input".

```
<div id="preview">
  <label id="companyName" class="workExperience">
                                This is my company
  </label>
</div>
<div id="edit">
  <label>Company Name: </label>
  <input type="text" id="companyNameInput" />
</div>

$(document).ready(function(e){

    $('#companyNameInput').bind('change', function(ev) {

        $(this).closest('#edit').prev().find('#companyName').html($(this).val());

    });


});
​
```

[test](http://jsfiddle.net/SGdQw/)